# How to make UIToolbar overlay programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Most of my camera overlay screen is covered by an opaque overlay. For the remaining portion, I would like to add a `UIToolbar` with several buttons. Please do mention how to make these buttons clickable programmatically too!

Here is how I added my overlay, which appears perfectly.

```
- (UIView*)CommomOverlay  {
    //Both of the 428 values stretch the overlay bottom to top for overlay function. It doesn't cover it. 
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,428)];
    UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,428)];
    [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
    [view addSubview:FrameImg];
    return view; 
}
```

Similarly, how would I add a working toolbar(clickable and fully function able with 2 buttons on it)?

Comment: what is a camera overlay screen?

Comment: @tiguero I'm guessing he means UIImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (in your viewDidLoad, or viewWillAppear)

```
//create toolbar and set origin and dimensions
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 428, 320, 32)];

//create buttons and set their corresponding selectors
UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(button1Tap:)];
UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:@selector(button2Tap:)];

//if you want custom icons, use something like this:
UIBarButtonItem *button3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1_portrait.png"] landscapeImagePhone:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1_landscape.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(button3Tap:)];

//add buttons to the toolbar
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1, button2, nil]];

//add toolbar to the main view
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

- create selectors like this:

  ```
  -(void)button1Tap:(id)sender {
      NSLog(@"Button 1 was tapped!");
      // do whatever needs to happen
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was quite helpful! But I have another question, hope you'd care to shed some insight. I have created a done button my custom toolbar. I am using the ZBar SDK which allows me to scan barcodes, the default version stops scanning after one barcode and shows you the barcode result. I want to scan multiple barcodes and I want to dismiss the UIImagePickerController when I click on the done button on the UIToolBar.

Comment: Glad it helped. It is best to post it as a separate question, so it will be useful for others as well...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, all you have to do is add a `UIToolBar` to the function:

```
- (UIView*)CommomOverlay  {
    //Both of the 428 values stretch the overlay bottom to top for overlay function. It doesn't cover it.
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,428)];
    UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,428)];
    [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
    UIToolbar *myToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(myFunction)];
    [myToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myBarButtonItem, nil] animated:YES];
    [FrameImg addSubview:myToolBar];
    [view addSubview:FrameImg];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was good insight! Now if you'd be kind enough to answer my other question(please check my profile)?